# Unable to send data from controller to another controller only in IE

Tags: javascript

```js
In my first controller

`$scope.onClickPrintSummary = function(val) {
      var popup = $window.open('resources/html/AcaCashCheckPrintSummary.html','_blank');
      popup.duplicateInd = val;
      popup.acaPrntSmry = $scope.acaHeaderInfo;
     };`

> In my 2nd controller

    .controller(
    'printSummaryController',
    function($scope, $rootScope, $compile, $window) {
     $scope.prntSmry = $window.acaPrntSmry;
});
```

But it is working fine in chrome.
But in IE sometimes it is coming and sometimes not.

Comment: Maybe you have a popup blocker?

Comment: Want to know how to use service also if possible

Comment: popup is coming but the data is not binding properly only in Ie

Comment: i found it. Its working fine with $window.opener in the 2nd controller